# cisco 2610XM telnet and http username and passwords

Tags: command-line, router

I have a cisco 2610XM for which they gave me a username and password. I can access and login into the web gui. from there I show the running configuration, it contains:

```
line vty 0 4
 password 123
!
!
```

Now when I telnet into the router it asks for a *username* at the first step.

Considering that I have GUI level 15 access to the *router via web*.

- How can I know the username for which I know the password? OR
- How can I configure additional telnet username/password?

**UPDATE**
Below shows my level 15 access and the problem to configure terminal:

```
http://myipaddress/level/15/exec/-/configure/http
----------------
Output
Command base-URL was: /level/15/configure/-
Complete URL was: /level/15/configure/-/config/ter/CR 
Command was:  config ter
----------------
config ter
        ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Comment: you have noted that the password is not encrypted (no service password-encryption), so it is actually 123

Answer (score 0):

The telnet access on Cisco IOS is divided in virtual terminal lines (VTY) and you can configure individual settings for each one, like one specific password.

Config one specific username and password and then try to connect again.

Eg.

> enable
>
> config ter
>
> username alfa alfa123

your username will be alfa and password alfa123

Comment: thanks a lot for your response but my access is via web-gui, kindly please see the UPDATE section in my question.

Comment: UPDATE: I finally used console cable to obtain terminal access, But still eagerly want to know if it is possible via web interface "configure http"